# Combinatorics - How many students are there?

Tags: combinatorics

Here's my question: " In a class, two students in a class are to be chosen for a quiz. It can be done in 378 different ways. How many students are there in the class?".

Now I already know the answer, which is 28 students. I get that you need to multiply 378*2 = 756. Then you can type in x*(x-1) = 756, and find out that x = 28. But to be 100% sure, when you multiply 378 with 2, is it because you then find out all the ways you can choose two students when the order is important? Why is that so ?, I don't understand exactly why we need to do that? I'm really thankful for any answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: remind that the possible combinations of $k$ elements chosen among a total of $N$ elements are given by

$${N \choose k}=\frac{N!}{k!(N-k)!}$$